# What's the best way to have a "multitype" member variable in a class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, type-conversion

I'm currently working on adding new functionality to an already defined class in our codebase, and I'm running into issues due to not having encountered a problem like this before (I'm still fairly new to C++/coding). Below is a simplified version of the class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();

  Input ReturnInput() { return fizz.GetFizzInput(); }
  Output ReturnOutput() { return fizz.GetFizzOutput(); }

private:
  Fizz fizz;
};
```

I'm trying make it such that the member variable `fizz` can be of a different type `Buzz`, and call specific methods (i.e. `GetBuzzOutput/Input()`) that are only implemented in the `Buzz` class. Both `Fizz` and `Buzz` inherit from the same parent class, but that parent class does not implement these specific methods.

The following are some things I've thought about as options. All of them require adding an argument to `Foo`'s constructor and an additional member variable to let us differentiate which type we want - either `Fizz` or `Buzz`.

1. Add a second member variable of type `Buzz` and use either member variable as desired. This doesn't seem ideal because every time `Foo` is constructed, one of these member variables will be unused.
2. Change the member variable to a pointer to the base class of `Fizz` and `Buzz`, and use `dynamic_cast` to downcast to the appropriate type when calling the specific methods. I don't think this is a great idea either, but I'm less clear on why - it's mostly just a feeling.
3. Split `Foo` into two classes, `FooFizz` and `FooBuzz` (each of which has either `Fizz` or `Buzz` as a member variable), and instantiate the appropriate version depending on which one we want. This seems like the best option, but maybe there's some unseen issue I haven't understood.

Is there a better way to go about this? Am I missing something that would make this much easier? I can't implement virtual methods in the parent class of `Fizz` and `Buzz`, unfortunately.

Thanks very much for any advice.

Comment: Another option: `std::variant<Fizz, Buzz>`

Comment: Wouldn`t generics and polymorphism solve your problem?

Comment: sounds like you already have a base class for Fizz and Buzz, so just add a pointer of that base class in Foo and then when you create the Foo instance create the appropriate instance e.g. `std::unique_ptr<MyBase> fizzbuzz;` .. `fizzbuzz = std::make_unique<Buzz>();` or `fizzbuzz = std::make_unique<Fizz>();  `

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts. Unfortunately, we're locked on a version of C++ before C++17, so I can't make use of `std::variant`. I don't think I can use polymorphism because the compiler complains the object does not have the associated methods implemented when I try to call the specific methods (i.e. `GetFizzInput/Output`). I could maybe `dynamic_pointer_cast` to get the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a given Foo object doesn't need to be able to switch from holding-a-Fizz to holding-a-Buzz at runtime, C++ templates would give you the flexibility you need without the code duplication of writing both a FooFizz and a FooBuzz class:

```
template <class T> class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();

  Input ReturnInput() { return t.GetInput(); }
  Output ReturnOutput() { return t.GetOutput(); }

private:
  T t;
};

typedef Foo<Fizz> FooFizz;
typedef Foo<Buzz> FooBuzz;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! One question, if I use a template class, wouldn't that prevent me from using the specific versions of the functions associated with `Fizz` and `Buzz` (i.e. `GetFizzInput/Output`)?

Comment: It would make it difficult (but not impossible); the best solution would be if you can find a common set of methods that work for both `Fizz` and `Buzz` so that everything "just works".  Since (from your description) it sounds like both `Fizz` and `Buzz` are already both subclasses of the same base class, you're already halfway there.